# How can I change the listModel of an listview when I click on a button?

Tags: qt, listview, qml

In my code I want to change the `ListModel` of my `ListView` when I click on the button. My code doesn't work, how I can fix it?

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool typelist: false

    Component {
        id: l1
        ListModel{
            ListElement { test: "blue" }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: l2
        ListModel{
            ListElement { test: "red" }
            ListElement { test: "blue" }
        }
    }

    Component {
        id: deleg
        Rectangle {
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            color: test
        }
    }

    ListView {
        id: list
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.75
        delegate: deleg
    }

    Button {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.heigth * 0.25
        anchors.bottom: parent.bottom
        onClicked: {
            if(typelist == false) {
                list.model = Qt.createComponent(l1)
                typelist =! typelist
            }
            else {
                list.model = Qt.createComponent(l2)
                typelist =! typelist
            }
        }
    }
}
```

When I click, I get this error:

> ReferenceError: test is not defined

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are using the wrong function.

[`Qt.createComponent`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-qt.html#createComponent-method) takes a url as a parameter and returns a new `Component`.
You already have a `Component`, so you don't need that function.

You need [`Component.createObject`](https://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qml-qtqml-component.html#createObject-method). It creates an instance of an object from a `Component`.

Your code then becomes

```
list.model = l1.createObject();
```

Note that you don't have to use `Component` in your example if you don't mind instantiating both models from the start:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    id: window
    visible: true
    width: 640
    height: 480

    property bool typelist : false

    ListModel{
        id: listModel1
        ListElement { test: "blue" }
    }

    ListModel{
        id: listModel2
        ListElement { test: "red" }
        ListElement { test: "blue" }
    }

    ListView {
        id: listView
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.height * 0.75
        model: typelist ? listModel1 : listModel2
        delegate: Rectangle{
            width: parent.width
            height: 50
            color: model.test
        }
    }

    Button {
        width: parent.width
        height: parent.heigth*0.25
        anchors.bottom:parent.bottom
        onClicked: typelist=!typelist
    }
}
```